# Finding a signal using Fourier data

Tags: fourier-series, signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

Hi everyone I'm a bit stuck in an exercise in finding the letter Does anyone have an idea how I can find the letter to develop for him the exponential Fourier column using the data?

**These are the data**

1. x(t) Real and cycle at T = 3

**and more data in the picture:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1U4Q.png)

How can I find x(t)?

Comment: 1) What do yo mean by "letter". Is it "latter" ? 2) Besides, the data you give is completely **cryptic** wrt to Fourier Transform I am used to...

Comment: 1)sorry no "letter" i mean "signal"  and 2)My lecturer gave me a hint and said it was somehow related to the shock train

Comment: Use a software like matlab and apply invfft(...) (inverse fast Fourier transform) to your data in order to retrieve the original signal.